# Override your packages in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

How do I override my own classes or classes of my packages?

Overriding ExtJS classes works. But I can not do the overriding of my classes.

It's about the option `Ext.Class.override`: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-override

These are the folders that are created using Sencha Cmd:
`{Workspace} \ packages \ local \ {package} \ overrides`,
`{Workspace} \ {application} \ overrides`

Answer (score 1):

It does work for your own classes the same way it does for Sencha classes. Not sure why you need it, and not sure why it doesn't work for you, but I have just created a new override in my application:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.MyOwnOverrideTest',{
    override: 'MyApp.view.main.HeaderBar',
    constructor: function() {
        console.log('Constructor of override called!');
        this.callParent(arguments); // Call original constructor.
    }
});
```

and added it to the requires in `Application.js` like the dozens of overrides I have for original ExtJS classes:

```
requires: [
    'MyApp.override.MyOwnOverrideTest',
```

Then I loaded the application in my browser. The class is instantiated once on application startup, and I found the expected output in browser console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjpuv.png

Please note that I could have added the line to my own class and no one would note the difference, so an override does not make sense for classes that are part of the same project/package.

Comment: These are the folders that are created using Sencha Cmd:    
`{workspace}\packages\local\{package}\overrides`,  
`{workspace}\{application}\overrides`

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'extend' property of the new class definition.  For example,

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.ItemMenu', {
   extend: 'MyApp.view.main.AbstractMenu',
   ...
```

Comment: This is about the option http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-override